# Configure Vim to always open first fold only

Tags: vim, folding

Is it possible to configure Vim to always open first fold only in a given file (and left the rest of them closed)?

Preferably I would like to setup Vim to do this for specific files but a general setting would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the first *level* of folding, that's controlled by the `'foldlevel'` option, and `'foldlevelstart'` governs its initial value. So `:set foldlevelstart=1` would do that.

---

If you mean the first fold in a file, you can do that via a sequence of commands:

- `zM` closes all folds
- `ggzj` goes to the first fold in the buffer
- `zo` / `zO` opens one / all levels under the cursor.

To apply this automatically, use:

```
:autocmd BufWinEnter * normal! zMggzjzo
```

Comment: Thanks. I meant first fold in a file. Is it possible to configure this for a single file (rather than a file type)?

Comment: Just specify the path to the file instead of `*` in the `:autocmd`.

Comment: That way I will have to modify my `.vimrc` each time. Can I add it inside the file I want to alter the behaviour for (same way as I would do: `vim:set ft=txt`)?

Comment: No, modelines only allow setting built-in options. You could use one of the "local vimrc" plugins to set this for a particular directory, though.

Comment: Well your autocmd could examine file content for some keyword string before acting.